# How to add data and datetime index at last row dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this.

test = df.loc[:, ['Close']]
print(test)

It show result like this.

```
                Close
Date                 
2019-02-14  23.700001
2019-02-15  23.799999
2019-02-18  23.700001
```

I want to add **Date 2019-02-19 Close 25** at the last row.

I try to add like this.

```
df.loc[0,:] = 1
```

It show error.

```
TypeError: cannot insert DatetimeIndex with incompatible label
```

How to add data and datetime index at last row dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write row name in datetime format, not its index:

```
df.loc["2019-02-19"] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you generically want to do this operation on your last row (assuming your data is sorted) you could do the assignment via `iloc[]` which gives you array-like indexing:

```
df.iloc[-1, :] = 1
```

Which takes the last row (`-1`) and all of the columns (`:`) and assigns the value 1 to them